# Help setting up Zend Framework include paths on server

Tags: zend-framework, include-path, nearlyfreespeech

I'm struggling to get my Zend driven website work on a remote server, and I'm not clear on what's going wrong with the include paths. I'd really appreciate some help as I've tried every permutation I can think of, and I suspect I've missed something fundamental.

The exception I'm getting is:

```
Message: Plugin by name 'Headtitle' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/f5/metamusic/protected/application/views/helpers/
Stack trace:

#0 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('Headtitle')
#1 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'headtitle')
#2 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(344): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('headtitle')
#3 [internal function]: Zend_View_Abstract->__call('headtitle', Array)
#4 /f5/metamusic/protected/application/views/scripts/search/index.phtml(3): Zend_View->headtitle('Search')
#5 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/View.php(108): include('/f5/metamusic/p...')
#6 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(888): Zend_View->_run('/f5/metamusic/p...')
#7 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(908): Zend_View_Abstract->render('search/index.ph...')
#8 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(929): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('search/index.ph...', NULL)
#9 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(968): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#10 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#11 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(523): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#12 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#13 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#14 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#15 /f5/metamusic/protected/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#16 /f5/metamusic/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#17 {main}
```

I don't understand why it seems to be attempting to include a library file from the application path. Also, the server has open_basedir() restriction in effect, so I I have to use a server symbol - `$_SERVER['NFSN_SITE_ROOT']` to access the root directory instead of `/`.

So, the folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
/public/index.php <- the site entry point
/protected/application <- the site source
/protected/library <- the Zend library directory from zf-minimal.tar.gz
```

This is my index.php:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', ($_SERVER['NFSN_SITE_ROOT'] . 'protected/application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    ($_SERVER['NFSN_SITE_ROOT'] . 'protected/library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

And this is my config.ini:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/"
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"

resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = ---
resources.db.params.password = ---
resources.db.params.dbname = ---

acl.roles.guest = null
acl.roles.member = guest
acl.roles.admin = member

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Comment: shouldn't it be calling headTitle with a capital 'T'?

Comment: Nice catch! Yes, that's fixed it. Must have slipped by as I'm developing on a windows machine. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be calling headTitle with a capital 'T'?